# Printing map values with only STL loops

Tags: c++, stl

i'm having a problem where i can't see what to do. I have to print map values with only STL loops, i can't use for loops while loops etc..

here's my map `std::map<std::string, Borrowed*> map;`

I'd rather not declare another function myself unless if it's really necessary to do that

Edit: I tried using for_each and copy function but if that's what you should use i don't see how you would use them

Comment: I guess you want std::for_each

Comment: @DieterLücking Yea but how do i use it, i tried using in a logical way but i don't see one

Comment: Also: std::copy with a std::ostream_iterator

Comment: @DieterLücking Tried that too but how would i print both values of the string and my pointer

Comment: What are "STL loops"?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::for_each` with a lambda that prints the element (using a `map<string, int>` for simplicitly, use your own code for printing `Borrowed*` elements).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m = { { "bla", 1 }, { "yada", 2 } };
    std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [](auto const& elem) {
        std::cout << "{ " << elem.first << ", " << elem.second << "}, ";
    });
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e8be339af70a3ca)

Note this uses C++14 generalized lambdas (with `auto` to deduce the parameter type). In C++11 you'd have to explicitly write that out, and in C++98 you'd have to write your own function object to the lambda's work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean STL algorithms:

Here is a `std::for_each` example (c++11):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::for_each(map.cbegin(), map.cend(), 
  [&](const std::pair<std::string, Borrowed*> &pair) {
    std::cout << pair.first // std::string (key)
      << " " << pair.second->XXX // Borrowed* (value) or whatever you want to print here
      << "\n";
});
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Comment: Thanks that seems to work! but i don't understand what & helps us to do here

Comment: We are not capturing the variable `map` here, since we are not using it in the lambda. We could actually omit the `&` here.[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)